# reversing time of thermally averaged cross section for 3->2 processes

Tags: thermodynamics, particle-physics, cosmology, phase-space

I am considering the process $a,b\to 1,2,3$ where all particles have the same (or approximately the same) mass. I have found a program [micrOMEGAs](https://lapth.cnrs.fr/micromegas/) which can calculate the thermally averaged cross section (TACS) 
$$\langle\sigma_{2\to 3}v\rangle$$
(using only one integral of $s$ see the paper of Gondolo and Gelmini "improved analysis"), but I want to calculate $\langle\sigma_{3\to 2}v^2\rangle$. CP symmetry can be assumed and Boltzmann statistics are assumed.

So by the definition of the TACS (or the thermal average) I should be able to calculate $\langle\sigma_{3\to 2}v^2\rangle$ with the following formula
$$\langle\sigma_{3\to 2}v^2\rangle=\frac{n_{a,eq}n_{b,eq}}{n_{1,eq}n_{2,eq}n_{3,eq}}\langle\sigma_{2\to 3}v\rangle$$
The problem however lies in the fact that $(\sigma_{2\to 3}v)$ contains in the calculation (phase space integral over the final states) the factor
$$
f=\frac{\sqrt{\lambda(s,s',m_3^2)}}{2\sqrt{s}}
$$
where $\lambda(d,e,c)=(d-e-c)^2-4ec$, $s=(p_1^\mu+p_2^\mu+p_3^\mu)^2$ and  $s'=(p_1^\mu+p_2^\mu)^2$ and this factor is not defined for $\sqrt{s}<\sqrt{s'}+m_3$  because $\lambda(s,s',m_3^2)<0$ (but since I want the processes $3\to 2$ the kinematics $\sqrt{s}>m_a+m_b$ should be always allowed). Unlike the factor $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda(s,m_a^2,m_b^2)}}$ in $\sigma$ (which gets cancelled by $v$ in $(\sigma v)$
 this factor cannot be cancelled. So is there a way to calculate $\langle\sigma_{3\to 2}v^2\rangle$ by using $\langle\sigma_{2\to 3}v\rangle$?

Comment: Your notation is not clear. Do you mean to scatter 3 particles off each other and get other 2 (a,b)  out?

Comment: Yes 3 particles are in the initial state and 2 particles are in the final state

Comment: I do not think this can be done analytically. It is true that feynman diagrams can be read in any direction,  for two to two. Any diagrams I have seen of two to three are too complicated and dependent on the interaction to be read  as three to two, imho.